# Slow slew-rate compared to the datasheet

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, comparator, multisim, rail-to-rail

I'm trying to create a 10 kHz PWM signal through use of op amps. In the output I'm using a TLV272IP op-amp working as a comparator:

[image]

[image]

Since it has as slew rate of at least 1.8 V/us this should give a rise and fall time of:

Vsat+ = 12 V -> trise/tfall = 12/1.8 = 6.67 us;

This is not what is happening in my simulation.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: _”op-amp working as a comparator”_ Why not a comparator if that’s what you need?

Comment: As one can see, the resolution of your display is too bad. You really should spend much pore data points (at least a factor of ten). More than that, do not forget that the slew rate is defined with negative feedback only.

Comment: Go to Custom Analysis Options, set GMIN = 1e-9, RSHUNT = 1e9, METHOD = Gear, and in Transient Analysis, initial and minimum timestep to 1µs or less.  If this still doesn't look great, try lower RELTOL.

Comment: Note that 741 (your first op-amp) has a slew rate of **0.5 V/us**. So 12/0.5= 24 us ...

Comment: @LvW  Sure? "the slew rate is defined with negative feedback"?

Comment: @Antonio yes, I am sure. It works for feedback only. This is due to the time delay within the opamp. In the very first moment the input step brings the first stage into saturation and this stage works as a current source......until the feedback brings this stage back into "normal" (linear) operation. It is this sequence which can be observed as an effect we call "slew rate". That means: A corresponding slew rate test requires an input step which can bring the opamp (without considering the feedback effect) into saturation. Microvolts are not enough .

Comment: Never tried this "measure". Seems to be only measurable (within specifications) in an invert configuration with very "low" resistors. No "saturation" is needed. I used 100 Ohm at input and 1k as feedback resistor. Symmetric square wave 50 mV peak. Found slew-rate 0.45 V/us which is near 0.5V/us for an LM741C.